# R geom_bar: Visualize both individual size and total size by groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, position, geom-bar

So I want to make a barplot to visualize both individual size and total size by groups.

To separate values by groups, I used `Position = 'dodge'`.
To plot total size, I used `stat = 'identity'`.
To visualize individual size, I used `aes(color='black')`.

These three seem not to work together.

```
# make fake data
t1 = tibble(type = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a'), Quantity = c(100, 200, 150, 50, 75), fill=c('1','1','1','2','2'))

# no dodge, correctly stacked
p1 = ggplot(t1) + 
  geom_bar(aes(type, Quantity, fill=fill, color='black'), 
           stat='identity', alpha=0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values='black', guide=FALSE)

# with dodge, overlap in same group
p2 = ggplot(t1) + 
  geom_bar(aes(type, Quantity, fill=fill, color='black'), 
           stat='identity', alpha=0.5, position='dodge') +
  scale_color_manual(values='black', guide=FALSE)

p1 / p2
```

[plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxgAb.png)

This example was modified from this [post](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2229) issued in 2017. In the post, the solution was to combine data points of the same group. But in my case, if data are combined, there won't be information to plot individual size. Since it's 2021, is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate totals first and try to plot. For example, this code produces the following plot. I am not sure if `fill` column is necessary

```
t1 = tibble(type = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a'), Quantity = c(100, 200, 150, 50, 75))
p2 = t1 %>% 
    group_by(type) %>% 
    mutate(total = sum(Quantity)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-type) %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_bar(aes(type, value, fill=name, color='black'), 
             stat='identity', alpha=0.5, position='dodge') +
    scale_color_manual(values='black', guide=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! If you look at the Quantity (red) group in type - a, you will find them overlapping. Can they be stacked together with black outlines around each of them?